# Transfer files with sockets in Python 3

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I have the following client-server socket app to upload a file to a server.

### Server code:

```
    import socket,sys,SocketServer

   class EchoRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
       def setup(self):
           print self.client_address, 'connected!'
           self.request.send('hi ' + str(self.client_address) + '\n')

       def handle(self):
           while 1:
                  myfile = open('test.txt', 'w')
                  data = self.request.recv(1024)
                  myfile.write(data)
                  print 'writing file ....'
                  myfile.close()

       def finish(self):
          print self.client_address, 'disconnected!'
          self.request.send('bye ' + str(self.client_address) + '\n')

  if __name__=='__main__':
          server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', 50000), EchoRequestHandler)
          server.serve_forever()
```

---

### Client code:

```
import socket
import sys 

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 50000

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = sock.recv(1024)

    date = open('file_t.txt').read()
    sock.sendall(data + "\n")
finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

However at the server side the console output is non stop "writing file ...." and in the end the file is not stored, It is an empty test.txt file

Comment: If you are going to go into an infinite loop, don't you want to have a break in there?

Answer (score 1):

You could improve your loop quite a bit.

1. Use `while True` rather than `while 1`. Sure it works and is less typing, but if you really wanted less typing then you should be using Perl. `while True` is easy enough that nearly anyone could guess at the meaning - `while 1` is just a holdover from when Python had no `True` or `False`
2. `socket.recv` returns an empty string when there's nothing more to read. Use that.
3. You're opening the file each time through the loop. That truncates it every time through the loop.

Here's what a better approach could look like:

```
def handle(self):
    # With block handles closing - even on exceptions!
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        data = 'fnord' # just something to be there for the first comparison
        while data:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            print('writing {!r} to file ....'.format(data))
            outfile.write(data)
```

No break is necessary with this approach - because rather than a `while True` it's `while data`. Strings will evaluate to `True` as long as they are non-empty, so this will continue to write data as long as there is data to write. Eventually, the sender will stop sending any data, the socket will close and data will be an empty string, which evaluates to False, and your loop will exit.

Comment: Why While True is better than while 1? Just out of curiosity

Comment: Should i put any break?

Comment: It does not work this approach. I still get an empty file

Comment: `1` is a holdover from earlier versions of Python that had no `True`. It's easier to understand `while True` - even non-programmers should be able to get that. No break is necessary here - because rather than a `while True` it's `while data`. This will continue to write data as long as there is data to write. Eventually, the sender will stop sending any data, the socket will close and `data` will be an empty string, which evaluates to `False`, and your loop will exit.

Comment: I just made a modification that should aid you in debugging. It will print out whatever data you're getting.

Comment: The file is written only when i terminate my client. If i don't file is created and is empty

Comment: Your client does need to disconnect, yes. And it *should* disconnect when it's finished uploading the file.

Comment: how this can change?i do not want my client to disconnect, i want to continue after the interaction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118276/discussion-between-wayne-werner-and-curious).